# Where do I place my image to Eclips read it?

Tags: jlabel, imageicon

I'm going to run following application in Eclips, but it doesn't show imageIcon. I'v placed my image in different folders, but it dosnt work.
My program doesn't make error, but only shows the text label, not image label.
Could you please help me ?
Thank you in advance.

```
package GUIpackage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LabelDemo 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JLabel northLabel = new JLabel( "North" );
        ImageIcon labelIcon = new ImageIcon( "bug1.png" );
        JLabel centerLabel = new JLabel( labelIcon );
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        application.add( northLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        application.add( centerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        application.setSize( 300, 300 ); // set the size of the frame
        application.setVisible( true ); // show the frame
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only by moving your image throughout the different folders in Eclipse won't make the image accessible. For retrieving the image you will need to write a loader method using a ClassLoader.

What you do is basically create your labelIcon with a NullPointer and later on assigning the actual ImageIcon to it by calling the loader Method:

```
ImageIcon labelIcon = null;
try {
    labelIcon = loadIcon("bug1.png");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

I worked a bit on the code and this would be a working solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class LabelDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LabelDemo ld = new LabelDemo();
}

public LabelDemo() {
    JLabel northLabel = new JLabel("North");
    ImageIcon labelIcon = null;
    try {
        labelIcon = loadIcon("bug1.png");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    JLabel centerLabel = new JLabel(labelIcon);
    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.add(northLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    application.add(centerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    application.setSize(300, 300); // set the size of the frame
    application.setVisible(true); // show the frame
}

public ImageIcon loadIcon(String iconName) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(loader.getResourceAsStream(iconName));
    return new ImageIcon(icon);
}
}
```

For this code to work you need to place the image into the `src` folder in Eclipse.

In your example however you need to create an instance of LabelDemo as otherwise you won't be able to call `this.getClass().getClassLoader();` as you can't use `this` in a static method.

Hope I could help you